# excel automation Vlookup functions in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

powershell script to automate excel functions unable to perform `Vlookup` function,
i have input excel file with two sheets,

```
**sheet1**  - machinename,status
**Sheet2**  - machinename,lastlogontime
```

i need to do a vlookup from **sheet2** to get status from

```
sheet1=VLOOKUP(A2,final!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

same formula I like to use in **powershell** in the below code.

below code gives error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

```
$v1 = "VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\Users\vtamilar\Desktop\UK[final.xlsx]'final!`$A:`$B,2,FALSE)"

$wb2.cells.item(2,3).value2 = $v1
```

Comment: Looks like a missing `\\` between UK AND [final.xlsx].

Comment: i missed here, gives same error after adding it,

Comment: $wb2.cells.item(2,3).value2 = $v1

these range values are correct ? i just copy paste from MS